# Displaying data from DB tables in single row if values duplicated

Tags: java

I have queried multiple tables and I am getting data . Now I want to show that data in tabular form such that if Ids repeated it will be in single row only.

I have queried like

```
 Query  "select a.id,b.status from A a,B b 

 List li = data from query;
 Iterator iterator = li.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(id+"-"+status)
 }
```

I am getting data as ,

```
**id                 status**        
  10                  G1
  10                  G2 
  10                  G3 
  15                  G1
  16                  
  17                  G1
  17                  G2
```

Now I wanted to show it as below (e.g. 10 is repeated 3 times so I wanted to show its 3 grades in single row, 15 once,16 no grade ,17 grade twice)

```
  id          statusfirst           statussecond     statusthird
  10           G1                    G2               G3
  15           G1                    NA               NA 
  16           NA                    NA               NA
  17           G1                    G2               Na
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a LinkedHashMap to accomplish such categorization and also keep the ids order.

Please find below the source code example:

```
    // put this line outside the loop of ids and statuses
    // In case your ids are Integers change the LinkedHashMap<String, String> to LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>.
    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> lh = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    String id = "1";
    String status = "G1";

    // put the below lines in the loop of ids and sstatuses
    if (id != null && !"".equals(id.trim())) {
        if (!lh.containsKey(id)) {
            final ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add(status);
            lh.put(id, al);
        } else {
            lh.get(id).add(status);
        }
    }

    Iterator<String> lhIter = lh.keySet().iterator();
    while (lhIter.hasNext()) {
        final String thisId = lhIter.next();
        final ArrayList<String> statusesAL = lh.get(thisId);
        final StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
        strB.append("id: '").append(thisId).append("'");
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : statusesAL) {
            strB.append(" status[").append(i).append("]: '").append(s).append("'");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(strB.toString());
    }
```

The output will look like this: id: '1' status[0]: 'G1'.

In case there are more statuses for an id the output will be like this: id: '1' status[0]: 'G1' status[1]: 'G2'.